# Where do I mail my application for a UK visa to after the biometrics?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, applications

I am based in the US and have completed the UK visa online. Where do I mail the application and supporting documents to after the biometrics?
Thanks
Charles

Answer (score 1):

Details are here https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa

The address is 
VFS Services USA Inc., UKVI Scanning Hub, 80 Broad Street, Floor 6, New York, 10004

Comment: The address does not change frequently, but it was different last year. You should check the official site to ensure that you have the correct address before mailing your package.